# Download files on iOS with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fetch-blob

I am building an app that lets the user download a PDF file when he clicks on a button.

I use the library react-native-fetch-blob for this purpose.

It works well on Android.

On iOS, the console log tells me the download has worked well, but:

- I don't see anything happening on screen (on Android, there is a notification that tells me the download is complete)
- I cannot find the file anywhere on the iPad. There is no "My files" folder or equivalent.

What is the right way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Try downloading some PDF reader on your iPhone and check if it will find it or not.

Comment: i'm shocked there isn't any answer . i've same problem

Answer (score 2):

The solution thats worked for me in iOS was use RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument function inside the then of fetch. This function open the file on the device file explorer where you have the option to download. Here is the code example:

```
downloadPDFiOS (uri) {
let uriSplitted = uri.split("/");
const fileName = uriSplitted.pop();
const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
RNFetchBlob
    .config({                
        path: dirs.DocumentDir + '/' + fileName,
        fileCache: true,
    })
    .fetch('GET', uri, {
        //some headers ..
    })
    .then((res) => {
        RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(res.data);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log('Error en el fetch: ', e);
    })
}
```